# How to handle the string separated by a comma in csvwriter processinggroup nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm having a csv file with two columns for example column A and Columb B. Column B consists of string value like this : I am, doing good. so when I try to insert this data into a database only the string I am is getting inserted. I just want to know what attribute I need to add to the process group so that I am, doing good will get inserted to the database

The attached image consists of the attributes in the current process group[image]

Comment: what is column value separator in your csv file? If it comma there is no easy way to handle this.

Comment: It’s comma separator now

Comment: Because of comma in your values, you should either change separator  or quate your value  in your original csv file.

Comment: Change value separator to for instance: `|`